# Custom loss function for training optimisation using python and sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the scikit-learn neural network toolbox sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor to train a regressor with an output vector of 24 nodes. I am looking to use an error function similar to dynamic time warping (but slightly simplified) to quantify the prediction error. I have written the function that quantifies the error between two input vectors but am not sure how to link this in with sklearn's MLP Regressor.

Q: Is it simply a case of defining a scoring object as shown here [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#defining-your-scoring-strategy-from-metric-functions) and feeding it into the training part.

Below is my defined loss function.

```
def MAAPE(actual,forecast,p,w):
error_array = np.zeros([len(actual), len(forecast)])
error_sum = 0

for i in range(len(actual)):
    for j in range(len(forecast)):            
        if abs(i-j)>w:
            error_array[i,j] = float('inf')
        else:
            error_array[i,j] = abs(actual[i] - forecast[j])/actual[i]        
    error_sum = error_sum + min(error_array[i,:])**p        
MAAPE = (error_sum**(1/p))/len(actual)    
return MAAPE
```

Comment: Please read the [help] on how to ask good questions. This question has two problems: 1) you didn't show any code, so it's too vague 2) you're asking more than one question in a single post - please ask focused questions, with a single, concrete problem, best illustrated with code.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance @BartoszKP. Have added code of my loss function and also removed the extra question

Comment: Thanks, this looks much, much better. One last hint, to maximize the probability of receiving an answer: questions formulated this way ("Is it simple a case of...") make a most straightforward answer come to mind: just try it and see if it is or not :) It would be better if you stated what doesn't work in your sample code (e.g. what's the current vs the expected result).

Comment: So, If I am understanding correctly, you want to compare actual and predicted values according to your loss function. You have defined that function so just call on it with data. Or you want to use it in any of the sklearn inbuilt utilities. If latter, please post the code into which you want to use your function.